# css divs in div overlapping in wrong way

Tags: html, css, overlap

this is a responsive design

https://fiddle.jshell.net/f56fpzn9

i did what i want for mobile view (adjust to see), however in the wide view
the textTitle is overlapping with the textBox
and the contentBox didn't scratch to fit the size of content

probably the problem of position!?
i've tried for different settings, still can't get what i want
perhaps it's off-standard, suggest a proper way if appropriate
please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had position absolute on a couple of divs that need to be overridden, I have used `position: static` though `position: initial` may have worked too.

You also needed to override the `min-height` of one element, I used `min-height: auto`

The structure of the HTML needed to be tweaked slightly, the image box is now it's own container which helps to push the rest of the content underneath it.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/f56fpzn9/2/

Have a read through the code and let me know if there is something I missed.

Comment: i actually want the title to be displayed under the photo in the wide view

Comment: No problem, glad to help.